# Suppress verbose output when something goes wrong with ogr2ogr

Tags: gdal, error, ogr2ogr

Whenever `ogr2ogr` is not able to read a file, it seems to produce pages of output:

```
Unable to open datasource `file.geojson' with the following drivers.
  -> ESRI Shapefile
  -> MapInfo File
  -> UK .NTF
  -> SDTS
  -> TIGER
  -> S57
  -> DGN
  -> VRT
  -> REC
  -> Memory
  -> BNA
  -> CSV
  -> NAS
  -> GML
  -> GPX
  -> LIBKML
...
```

Is there a way to suppress this incredibly annoying output? My workaround is:

```
ogr2ogr ... 2>&1 | grep -v '^  ->'
```

Comment: I do not know any other option. What is your suggestion for a nice output?

Comment: Oh, just skipping the list. It's never relevant. It sort if implies that the problem is you're opening some super obscure that GDAL doesn't support, whereas the actual problem is always something wrong with the file, or the PostGIS connection or whatever.

Comment: It is not right to say that it is never relevant. GDAL may be  compiled without support for your file format or database and then fixing the file or PostGIS connection or whatever will not help.

Comment: Ok, point taken. IMHO though, this kind of output is very spammy and should be reserved for an explicit request to list drivers.

Comment: It does not report a list of all drivers, it is listing the drivers which were tried and which all failed. Compare `ogrinfo --formats` and `ogrinfo foo.txt`. The latter does not list CSV driver because it was not tried (by default CSV driver is trying to open only files with .csv extension). I consider that while shorter message would be nice sometimes the current message is good as default.

Comment: Well, you're certainly very welcome to your opinion :) Even if you in general want to see this very verbose output, perhaps you'd agree that there are times when you'd like to suppress it with an argument or an environment variable?

Comment: I already wrote "while shorter message would be nice sometimes". I was also probably wrong with my TXT/CSV example. If all the drivers are really listed the message does not give more information than "Oops, something went wrong" of "Could not open datasource with any configured driver". However, there is no workaround that I know at the moment and chat on this forum will not lead to any action. Write to gdal-dev mailing list and if the feedback supports you make a feature request to GDAL issue tracker.

Comment: Isn't it better to focus on using an ogr2ogr command so that it *works*?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. A script that runs `ogr2ogr` can't anticipate every cause of failure. The issue that inspired this question is a script that loads 15 different files. If one fails, it produces all this spammy output that pushes the actual error message off the top of the screen.

Comment: You'll not win many friends by describing an error message as spam. Instead of complaining about it, make it work correctly.